# What Block/Item ID's are save to use for a mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am making a mod for minecraft and I want to know which ID's can be used and which ones are taken by the game allready? I mean which Block/Item ID's (basically a number used to load a block in minecraft)

which ID's are safe to use for my own mod?

Comment: That's going to be a rather large list, and will depend on what other mods users have installed.  The best answer we can probably give to this is, "How do I find out what IDs are currently being used?"

Comment: I haven't installed any mods, I am making one so I need to know which ID's are used by ONLY minecraft itself

Comment: But in order for your mod to work with others, you have to make sure you're not using the same IDs that others do.  Otherwise, your mod is the only one that someone can use that adds blocks.  Unless that's what you're going for.

Comment: In 1.8, Minecraft item IDs are being changed from numbers to strings. So item 1 becomes `minecraft:stone`. So this is really a moot point.

Comment: @Unionhawk Modfing for 1.8 is currently experimental, so 1.7.10 is still the "current" version, modding-wise.

Comment: Well. It'as still far away from being released so I guess it's for personal use temporarily and I will deal with that stuff afterward.

Comment: @Unionhawk I am modding 1.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values) Minecraft uses all the block ID's from 0-197. Since unmodded block data is stored in 8 Bit binary, you have 198-256.

If you want your mod to be usable with any others, or in case of future update that adds blocks, You should make it editable in a config file.

Comment: not so many....

Answer (score 1):

Use a high number, and try it. The game will tell you (in a crash report) if you've used an invalid or taken ID.

Once you've found a free ID, you're not done yet though. Use it as the default, but add a config file and read it from there so that end-users can change it. This makes it possible to fix ID conflicts between different mods and makes ID conflicts people run into not your problem.

Comment: There should be no ID conflicts with new Forges....Forge automatically deals with it.